# scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis return null values for some vectors in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, similarity, distance

I am using scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis to calculate distance between two vectors but i'm getting null values for some vector I don't know why? null value is possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is important to include your test cases when you encounter a potential bug.

Without further information, looking at the formula of Mahanologis distance.
$$\sqrt{(u-v)^TV^{-1}(u-v)}$$
It is possible to obtain an error if $V$ is not positive definite as the input for the square root might be negative.

Comment: yes right exactly that's what happened in my case, thanks